# What happens when all items in a drop down list are selected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I haven't found this answer anywhere online. In SSRS 2008, when using a parameter that allows for multiple selections, if "Select All" is checked will all available values be returned in a comma separated list?

Comment: Yes, all values are returned in a comma separated list. You can confirm yourself in a simple test with a report connecting to a database and checking the database call in SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: To add a bit more clarification:  If your SQL is embedded into your report, the parameter will be replaced by a comma separated list of string values - for example: *'cat','dog','giraffe'*.  If you pass the parameter to a Stored Procedure, the stored procedure will receive a single string of comma separate values - for example: *'cat,dog,giraffe'*.  You can use an IN operation on a multi-value parameter in SQL embedded in your report, but not on a parameter passed to a stored procedure (you'll need to parse the parameter first).

Answer (score 0):

The parameter values are held internally by SSRS in an Array.

How they are passed to SQL depends on how you reference it in SQL, and also the Parameters page of the Dataset definition in SSRS.

The typical style is to reference the parameter in the WHERE clause of a SQL statement e.g.

`WHERE My_Column IN ( @My_Parameter)`

By default, this will set the reference on the Dataset's Parameters page to:

`=Parameters!My_Parameter.Value`

This acts as if it is passing a comma separated list, but that's not the actual mechanism.